# Display database values on option

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile, html-select

I am trying to display the saved data in the database on select before a user can update other choice. I am not really sure how to code it. Can anyone come out with possible solution? Had tried many ways but unable to do so.

Update: I have found out the problem why the options does not show.

This is my code:

`

```
$consentId = $_GET['consent_id'];

$retrieveConsent = "SELECT * FROM consent, leavetype WHERE consent.type_of_leave = leavetype.type_of_leave";
$retrieveResult = mysqli_query($link, $retrieveConsent) or die("Retrieve Error" . mysqli_error($link));

$queryleavetype = "SELECT * FROM leavetype";
$queryleaveresult = mysqli_query($link, $queryleavetype) or die("Leave Retrieve Error " . mysqli_error($link));

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($retrieveResult);


mysqli_close($link);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Edit Consent </title>
</head>
<body>
            <div class="ui-content">
                <h3><b>Edit Leave</b></h3>
                <form action="doEditConsent.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">

                    <input type="hidden" name="cId" value="<?php echo $row['consent_id']; ?>"/>

                    <label for="dateFrom" ><b>Date From:</b></label>
                    <input type="date" id="dateFrom" name="newDateFrom" value="<?php echo $row['consent_date_from']; ?>" required>
                    <br>

                    <label for="dateTo" ><b>Date To:</b></label>
                    <input type="date" id="dateTo" name="newDateTo" value="<?php echo $row['consent_date_to']; ?>" required>
                    <br>

                    <label for="reason" ><b>Leave Type:</b></label>
                    <select name="leaveType" id="leaveType" data-mini="true">
                        <?php
                        while ($rowleave = mysqli_fetch_array($queryleaveresult)) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rowleave['type_of_leave']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $rowleave['leave_type']; ?>
                            </option>
                            <?php
                        };
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>

                    <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" type="submit" >Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: is the query correct?? i mean print the result from query and check if its returning required values...

Comment: The query is correct. Tested on phpMyAdmin before writing down.

Comment: close connection at the end of your page `mysqli_close($link);`

Comment: @PayerAhammed It is unnecessary to put mysqli_close($link); at the end as you need not always open the connection at all time when user navigate in the page. Closing right after query will do and have better performance. The whole php will stop running and 'die' if the query is wrong.

Comment: why use this in your code ` };` ?

Comment: @PayerAhammed Oh, thanks for spotting. Should only have `}` and remove the semi-colon. Tested after removing, doesn't really matter if its there or not.

Comment: Inside the while loop use `var_dump($rowleave);` to make sure query result is present

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hopefully it will help you:

```
<select name="leaveType" id="leaveType" data-mini="true">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
    $previous_selected_value = 'previous_selected_value';//get the previous value and assign it to this variable
    while ($rowleave = mysqli_fetch_array($queryleaveresult)) {
        $selected = ($rowleave['type_of_leave'] == $previous_selected_value) ? " selected='selected'" : "";
        echo '<option value="'.$rowleave['type_of_leave'].'"'.$selected.'>'.$rowleave['leave_type'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but unfortunately the retrieving is not working